# Is there a vectorized way to operate on a different number of values per column in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

In MATLAB, is there a more concise way to handle discrete conditional indexing by column than using a for loop? Here's my code:

```
x=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
w=[5 3 2];

q=zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:3
    q(i)=mean(x(x(:,i)>w(i),i));
end
q
```

My goal is to take the mean of the top x% of a set of values for each column. The above code works, but I'm just wondering if there is a more concise way to do it?

Comment: Are you just trying to take the mean of a column after you exclude outliers?  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: My goal is to take the mean of the top x% of a set of values for each of a series of runs.  I have a matrix with a column of data for each run and used the prctile function to determine my condition for each run.  Although the above code works, it seems like there may be a more concise way accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you were using the function [PRCTILE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html), which would indicate that you have access to the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/). This gives you yet another option for how you could solve your problem, using the function [NANMEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/nanmean.html). In the following code, all the entries in `x` less than or equal to the threshold `w` for a column are set to [NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nan.html) using [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html), then the mean of each column is computed with [NANMEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/nanmean.html):

```
x(bsxfun(@le,x,w)) = nan;
q = nanmean(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to index the columns the way you want. This may be faster than a for loop, but it also creates a matrix y that is the size of x.

```
x=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9];
w=[5 3 2];

y = x > repmat(w,size(x,1),1);
q = sum(x.*y) ./ sum(y)
```

I don't claim this is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to solve your original problem: You have an array, and you want to know the mean of the top x% of each column.

```
%# make up some data
data = magic(5);

%# find out how many rows the top 40% are
nRows = floor(size(data,1)*0.4);

%# sort the data in descending order
data = sort(data,1,'descend');

%# take the mean of the top 20% of values in each column
topMean = mean(data(1:nRows,:),1);
```